# angular-scroll not working...something missing?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, smooth-scrolling

I'm making a website using angular, and I want to be able to click on a specific element and make the page scroll down smoothly to a particular div.
It's not working right now, and I'm not sure if I've missed something in my setup for this.

I've done `bower install angular-scroll --save-dev` which successfully added the angular-scroll folder to my bower_components, and the dependency to my bower.json file.

I've added the line `<script src="bower_components/angular-scroll/angular-scroll.js"></script>` to my index.html file.

And now the two relevant elements (the one I want to click and the one I want to scroll to) look like:

```
<a du-smooth-scroll="mainContent" du-scrollspy>Scroll down</a>
...
<div id="mainContent"> ... </div>
```

(I'm not using href="#mainContent" in my `<a></a>` tag because when I do, it seems to mess with my url, trying to add "mainContent" to the end of it)

Any ideas what might be going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the working sample for what you want I believe :)

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);
app.controller('HeaderCtrl', function($scope) {
});

app.service('anchorSmoothScroll', function(){
    
    this.scrollTo = function(ID) {
  // This scrolling function 
        // is from http://www.itnewb.com/tutorial/Creating-the-Smooth-Scroll-Effect-with-JavaScript
        var startY = currentYPosition();
        var stopY = elmYPosition(ID)-110; //value to set where is the end point to stop. Top margin 160px;
        var distance = stopY > startY ? stopY - startY : startY - stopY;
        if (distance < 100) {
            scrollTo(0, stopY); return;
        }
        var speed = Math.round(distance / 100);
        if (speed >= 20) speed = 20;
        var step = Math.round(distance / 100); //adjust the scrolling speed.
        var leapY = stopY > startY ? startY + step : startY - step;
        var timer = 0;
        if (stopY > startY) {
            for ( var i=startY; i<stopY; i+=step ) {
                setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
                leapY += step; if (leapY > stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
            } return;
        }
        for ( var i=startY; i>stopY; i-=step ) {
            setTimeout("window.scrollTo(0, "+leapY+")", timer * speed);
            leapY -= step; if (leapY < stopY) leapY = stopY; timer++;
        }
        
        function currentYPosition() {
            // Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            if (self.pageYOffset) return self.pageYOffset;
            // Internet Explorer 6 - standards mode
            if (document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                return document.documentElement.scrollTop;
            // Internet Explorer 6, 7 and 8
            if (document.body.scrollTop) return document.body.scrollTop;
            return 0;
        }
        
        function elmYPosition(ID) {
            var elm = document.getElementById(ID);
            var y = elm.offsetTop;
            var node = elm;
            while (node.offsetParent && node.offsetParent != document.body) {
                node = node.offsetParent;
                y += node.offsetTop;
            } return y;
        }

    };
    
});
app.controller('ScrollCtrl', ['anchorSmoothScroll', '$location', '$scope',
  function (anchorSmoothScroll, $location, $scope) {
    $scope.gotoStep = function(x) {
      var newHash = 'step' + x;
      if ($location.hash() !== newHash) {
  
   $location.hash('step' + x);
   anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo('step' + x);
      } else {
        //$anchorScroll();
  anchorSmoothScroll.scrollTo('step' + x);
      }
    };
 
  }
]);
```

```css
/* Put your css in here */

nav{
  position:fixed;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html  ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.2.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.28/angular.js" data-semver="1.2.28"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
   <nav class="navbar navbar-default sidebar" role="navigation" ng-controller="ScrollCtrl">
   <div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="collapse navbar-collapse">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li id="doc1"><a href="" ng-click="gotoStep(1)"><span>one</span><span class="badge" style="float:right;">1</span></a></li>
     <li id="doc2"><a href="" ng-click="gotoStep(2)"><span>two</span><span class="badge" style="float:right;">2</span></a></li>
     <li id="doc3"><a href="" ng-click="gotoStep(3)"><span>three</span><span class="badge" style="float:right;">3</span></a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
    </div>
  </nav>
  <div id="step1" style="height:500px;background-color:red">
    <p>i am one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="step2" style="height:500px;background-color:green">
    <p>i am one</p>
  </div>
  <div id="step3" style="height:500px;background-color:blue">
    <p>i am one</p>
  </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

You can use directive for this too I have a solution for this as well. Please find the working snippet And Please Let me know if it was helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `<a href="mainContent" du-scrollspy>Scroll Down</a>` and to deal with the hash issue,

`angular.element('a[href*=#]').click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
});`

This listens for the click event and calls preventDefault to stop the browser from setting the hash.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old question, but for anyone experiencing this issue now, version 1.0.1 of angular-scroll has just been released and has broken things for some people. To fix this, go to your bower.json file and specify "1.0.0" (*not* "~1.0.0") for the angular-scroll version.